# Prepocessor ## Operator and variable

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to "generate" a function name by using the operator ## and a variable value. For example:

```
#define FUN_I(fun, fun_id)  fun##fun_id
#define FUN(fun, fun_id)    RECV_CB_FUN_I(fun, fun_id)

int foo0(int x) {
    // do something
}
int main()
{
   int i = 0;
   FUN(foo,i)(1);
}
```

Macro `FUN` generates `fooi`. Is there a way to get `foo0` somehow, or I have to use the actual number 0 in this case, e.g `FUN(foo, 0)(1);`

Cheers

Comment: This would create a function called `fooi`.

Comment: The preprocessor is not the right tool for doing this because macros are expanded an compile time. You need to look into function pointers.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. The answer is "no" but it doesn't solve anything. What's the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, the macro expansion is done at compile time, so the function name wouldn't be know at run time.

It is more appropriate to use function pointers and an array to them.

**Example:**

```
typedef int (*TFoo)(int);

int foo1(int x)
{
    printf("from foo1: x = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}

int foo2(int x)
{
    printf("from foo2: x = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}

TFoo foos[2] = {foo1, foo2};
#define foo(i, x) foos[i](x)
```

That's that. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

You have to use actual 0 (or another macro). Macro expansion is handled by the C pre-processor at compile time. It knows nothing about runtime values of variables.

Answer (score 1):

'c' preprocessing is a process of replacing macros with the text from their definitions. some operations like ## allow to add its argument as text into definitions. So, everything is done even before compilation starts.

As a result, in your case `FUN(fun,i)` will be substituted as text and form `funi`. The only limited way to build function names like you want is to use actual text values or other macros. Here are 2 examples which will work with pre-processing:

```
FUN(fun, 0)(1);
```

or

```
#define I 0
FUN(fun, I)(1);
```

In the last case `I` is a macro itself, therefore it also works. (it is always a good idea to name macro name in upper case letters).